# Lightweight charts: time scale with images

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

[How to make chart like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqaoH.png)

Images on time scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible and I don't think it will be implemented in the future in lightweight-charts library.